# Fulltext working on MySQL 5.6, not 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have 2 main tables (`professional_account` & `professional_profile`) and 3 sub tables (`prof_knows_about`, `prof_keywords` & `prof_recent_jobs`) which are **1:many off professional_profile**.

A FT search should match the search term in professional_profile.professional_statement, OR any row (for that professional_id) of prof_knows_about.knowledge_desc, OR any row of prof_keywords.keyword OR any row of prof_recent_jobs.job_title

In a 5.6.35 server it works as expected, but in 5.7.10 I only get results if the search term is in professional_profile.professional_statement or prof_knows_about.knowledge_desc - the search term is not found in the other two tables. Both servers run on freeBSD UNIX.

I tried both servers with the query pasted into the shell. Both also give same EXPLAIN output. Used a dump from the 5.7 on the 5.6 to ensure same data and table creates.

I did a show variables on both servers, but hard to compare as there are many extra values in the 5.7. Set both to same sql_mode.

Tables, query and explain listed below.

Is this an issue with my query, or my 5.7 server?

```
select email,  PROFILE.*
    FROM professional_account as ACC 
    join professional_profile as PROFILE on ACC.professional_id=PROFILE.professional_id 
    join prof_knows_about as KNOWS on PROFILE.professional_id=KNOWS.professional_id  
    join prof_keywords as KEYW on PROFILE.professional_id = KEYW.professional_id  
    join prof_recent_jobs as ROLES on PROFILE.professional_id=ROLES.professional_id    
    where status in ('LIVE','EDITS')  
    and (  
        match (knowledge_desc) against ('ramble')   
        or match (job_title) against ('ramble')  
        or match (keyword) against ('ramble')  
        or match (professional_statement) against ('ramble')  
        )   
    group by PROFILE.professional_profile_id



+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys                  | key             | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | KNOWS   | NULL       | ALL    | professional_id                | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                      |   43 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PROFILE | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,professional_statement | professional_id | 4       | xxx.KNOWS.professional_id |    1 |    28.57 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ACC     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY         | 4       | xxx.KNOWS.professional_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ROLES   | NULL       | ref    | professional_id                | professional_id | 4       | xxx.KNOWS.professional_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | KEYW    | NULL       | ref    | professional_id                | professional_id | 4       | xxx.KNOWS.professional_id |    2 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+




CREATE TABLE professional_account (
  professional_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (professional_id),
  KEY email (email)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE professional_profile (
  professional_profile_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  professional_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  status enum('BLANK','PART_WAIT','PART_APP','COMP_WAIT','COMP_APP','LIVE','EDITS') DEFAULT NULL,
  professional_statement text,
  PRIMARY KEY (professional_profile_id),
  KEY professional_id (professional_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY professional_statement (professional_statement),
  CONSTRAINT fk_professional_profile_professional_account FOREIGN KEY (professional_id) REFERENCES professional_account (professional_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE prof_knows_about (
  prof_knows_about_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  professional_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  knowledge_desc varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (prof_knows_about_id),
  KEY professional_id (professional_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY knowledge_desc (knowledge_desc),
  CONSTRAINT fk_prof_knows_about_professional_profile1 FOREIGN KEY (professional_id) REFERENCES professional_profile (professional_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE prof_keywords (
  prof_keywords_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  professional_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  keyword varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (prof_keywords_id),
  KEY professional_id (professional_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY keyword (keyword),
  CONSTRAINT fk_prof_keywords_professional_profile1 FOREIGN KEY (professional_id) REFERENCES professional_profile (professional_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE prof_recent_jobs (
  prof_recent_jobs_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  professional_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  job_title varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  experience tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (prof_recent_jobs_id),
  KEY professional_id (professional_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY job_title (job_title),
  CONSTRAINT fk_prof_recent_jobs_professional_profile1 FOREIGN KEY (professional_id) REFERENCES professional_profile (professional_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE prof_keywords (
  prof_keywords_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  professional_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  keyword varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (prof_keywords_id),
  KEY professional_id (professional_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY keyword (keyword),
  CONSTRAINT fk_prof_keywords_professional_profile1 FOREIGN KEY (professional_id) REFERENCES professional_profile (professional_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: you are missing the prof_recent_jobs table structure.

Comment: thanks, put in in now, second from last.

Comment: did you upgraded the new server from 5.6 to 5.7?

Comment: The 5.7 is on my development server in the office, I installed that. The 5.6 is on the live server setup by the hosting company. I used all the defaults and just have set the general_log in my,cnf - standard binary install otherwise